# rsync not working

Tags: rsync

How do I exclude a folder when using rsync ?

```
rsync -i /home/kong/.ssh/id_rsantu --exclude /media/kong/Elements/sgan/dataset/ /media/kong/Elements/sgan/ kongserver@35.123.456.78:~/
```

And this is the message I got. But I went into the server and did not see the copied file.

```
skipping directory .
<f..T...... id_rsantu
```

I included --exclude= but it is still copying from `/media/kong/Elements/sgan/dataset/` because I see

```
<f+++++++++ dataset/train/Ouchy-2-Left-crops/crossing/0000000159/0000012818.png
<f+++++++++ dataset/train/Ouchy-2-Left-crops/crossing/0000000159/0000012819.png
<f+++++++++ dataset/train/Ouchy-2-Left-crops/crossing/0000000159/0000012820.png
<f+++++++++ dataset/train/Ouchy-2-Left-crops/crossing/0000000159/0000012821.png
```

Comment: The syntax is `--exclude=PATTERN`, you missed an `=` there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use -r flag:

`rsync -r -i /home/kong/.ssh/id_rsantu --exclude /media/kong/Elements/sgan/dataset/ /media/kong/Elements/sgan/ kongserver@35.123.456.78:~/`

from man rsync:

`-r, --recursive             recurse into directories`

Comment: but its still copying stuff from /media/kong/Elements/sgan/dataset/

Comment: that's becasue your exclude should only include path of the copied path:
`--exclude dataset/` because `/media/kong/Elements/sgan` is where the sync starts